# Composed address in Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

On gmaps4rails docs there is this method:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
  self.address #describe how to retrieve the address from your model
end
```

How do I set a custom composed address there? I've tried:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
  self.address =  (address + ', ' + city + ', ' + state + ', ' + zip)
end
```

And it didn't work, I have the city state zip and address field in my table.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the method as follows:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{address}, #{city}, #{state}, #{zip}"
end
```